# UITableView cell collapse animation looks bad

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios11

I'm having a problem making cell collapse animation look consistently smooth.

Am image is worth a thousand words. Here's two GIFs of the same table view:

[image: Great]
[image: Terrible]

Collapsing works really well for cell "6", but not for "5". It looks like the entire UITableView content jumps up before performing the collapse animation.

I'm **not** using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for UITableView's `rowHeight`. Instead I'm providing row height by `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method and expanding/collapsing the cell using table view's `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates`. As you can see I'm also scrolling to the expanded row using `tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .none, animated: true)` (but only when expanding, so it probably doesn't matter).

Subclass of UITableViewController is embedded in an UINavigationController with large title and search bar (not visible here, because the content is scrolled down). The UINavigationController is embedded in UITabBarController.

Here's the relevant expand/collapse part. When passing a nil `indexPath` parameter, the already expanded cell will collapse.

```
func expandRow(at indexPath: IndexPath?) {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()

    if let ip = indexPath {
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: ip, at: .none, animated: true)
    }
}
```

This method calculates row height and is called by both `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` and `tableView(_:estimatedHeightForRowAt:)`:

```
private func heightForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    var height: CGFloat
    if selectedIndexPath == indexPath {
        // Add some height variety
        height = 300 + CGFloat((indexPath.row % 4) * 20)
    } else {
        height = 70
    }
    return height
}
```

Here's the GitHub repo: https://github.com/AleksanderMaj/CellCollapse

Any idea how to improve this?

This problem is dimension-sensitive (this issue might not be reproducible following the same steps on a device with a different screen size). This was recorded on an iPhone 7 simulator with iOS 11.3.

---

EDIT 1:
It's important to preserve the automatic scrolling to the expanded cell.

Comment: what do you think this two lines with `.beginUpdates() ` and `.endUpdates()` are doing?

Comment: As far as I understand this is a well-known technique that makes the table view update cell heights in animated fashion.
Cell height is calculated in the following way: (I pasted in the original question, because there's no code formatting in comments)

Comment: @AleksanderMaj did you find any solution?

Comment: @guru unfortunately no. I gave up a long time ago

Answer (score 6):

I was able to make is smooth with a minor change in your expand method:

```
func expandRow(at indexPath: IndexPath?) {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()

    if let ip = indexPath {
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: ip, at: .middle, animated: true)
    }
}
```

[image: Before] [image: After]

Comment: this solution will lead to unexpected jumps of most top and bottom cells https://monosnap.com/file/TBg6Wl9iZRoH9SUqVmaLSFYUO6V9zc

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but just as @TarasChernyshenko pointed out, it introduces other issues.

Answer (score 2):

Had this issue when resizing my row height for every row click. Almost same with @Taras' answer, although in here, need to remove the animation first, before assigning the saved contentOffset. Hope this helps :)

```
func expandRow() {
    let savedContentOffset = tableView.contentOffset

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
    tableView.layer.removeAllAnimations()

    tableView.setContentOffset(savedContentOffset, animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are scrolling to expanded row and that makes UITableView jumps a little.

So here is a refactored `expandRow(at:)` method:

```
func expandRow(at indexPath: IndexPath?) {
    self.contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()

    if let contentOffset = self.contentOffset {
        tableView.contentOffset = contentOffset
    }
}
```

also you need to add `var contentOffset: CGPoint?` property to your controller.

**UPDATE**
I was wrong, you don't need to put `selectedIndexPath = indexPath` btw `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` method. Updated code example

Comment: Thanks for your response. The scrolling part is only executed when expanding (i.e. when `indexPath != nil`), and it has no effect on collapsing the cell. It is not part of the problem.

The contentOffset part of your response doesn't do the trick at all. Expand the cell "5" and then scroll manually so that its bottom edge is aligned with the top of the tab bar. Then tap again on "5" to collapse it. It still jumps: https://youtu.be/kvyjKrWnlnM

Answer (score -1):

I have an idea.  I am not sure the trick is work as I thought.

Collapsible table has a feature that the height of the table view will change when it is expanding or collapsing.

If we use custom view inherited from UITableView, we can override the property of the view, contentSize and contentOffset.
Through overriding these two properties, we can make table view stop, disable scrolling, for a while.

```
var contentSizeChanging: Bool = false

override var contentSize: CGSize {
    willSet {
        contentSizeChanging = true
    }
    didSet {
        contentSizeChanging = false
    }
}

override var contentOffset: CGPoint {
    get {
        return super.contentOffset
    }
    set(newValue) {
        if contentSizeChanging { return }
        super.contentOffset = newValue
    }
}
```